# Is it possible to play skin animation in reverse? [Three.js]

Tags: three.js

How would I go about playing an animation backwards?

I've tried giving the animation handler negative delta but that just stops it. Subtracting the delta from this.currentTime of the animation doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [Three.js r69](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/r69) it's possible to play animations in reverse order by setting [`animation.timeScale = -1`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Animation/Animation) though only when `animation.loop = true`.

See [Reverse animation, feature request #5062](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5062) for more updates.

Comment: RIght, I suggested the change and it got through. :) Thanks for posting it here

Comment: To work with animation.loop = false (2023) action.time = action.getClip().duration;
action.setEffectiveTimeScale(-1);

Answer (score 1):

I am using r126

Set `action.loop = THREE.LoopPingPong` will play the clip with the choosen number of `action.repetitions`, alternately playing forward and backward. ([doc](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationAction.loop))