# Reverse Keyframe animation in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Really I would like to reverse a keyframe animation using `THREE.KeyFrameAnimation.update` with a negative number, appreciate this isn't supported natively, has anyone got any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to play skin animation in reverse? \[Three.js\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282035/is-it-possible-to-play-skin-animation-in-reverse-three-js)

Answer (score 3):

I actually found a solution to this for when you only want to play it once. I posted the full class here:

- https://gist.github.com/rtpHarry/2d41811d04825935039dfc075116d0ad

The important bit is:

```
  // will force the mixer to play in reverse no matter what
  playClipReverseByIndex_Forced(index) {
    this.action = this.mixer.clipAction(this.animations[index]);

    if(this.action.time === 0) {
        this.action.time = this.action.getClip().duration;
    }

    this.action.paused = false;
    this.action.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);      
    this.action.timeScale = -1;
    this.action.play();
  }
```

Comment: This works - setting `paused` to false is the key ingredient (one would thing that calling `play()` would reset `paused`, but oh well...)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `animation.timeScale = -1;`

But it works only when `animation.loop = true;`